# How can I bring the django filters for filtering and searching in a APIView instead of ListAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Given below was a code written in ListAPIview and now I have to change it to APIView. How can I bring the search, filtering and ordering in this? Please let me know in the comments if any more details are needed. Thanks in advance.

```
class DiscussionView(APIView):
    pagination_class = DiscussionPagination
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter, SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['title']
    ordering_fields = ['id']

def get(self, request, format=None):
    query = Discussion.objects.all()
    serializer = DiscussionSerializer(query, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = DiscussionSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `APIView` you should use [`GenericAPIView` DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) then you can simply use the `filter_queryset` method of the view which will use the specified `filter_backends` to filter the queryset. To paginate you can use the `paginate_queryset` method and `get_paginated_response` to return the paginated response:

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView


class DiscussionView(GenericAPIView):
    pagination_class = DiscussionPagination
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter, SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['title']
    ordering_fields = ['id']

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        query = self.filter_queryset(Discussion.objects.all()) # Here
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = DiscussionSerializer(query, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = DiscussionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: it works. but the pagination is not working now.

Comment: Thank you. You are the best.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution right here, its amazing and on point. tho I still have one question, why not use the APIView, I had to change my code to APIView and I also had to find ways to overcome the get_queryset in the GenericAPIView. any reasons why ??

Comment: @kaybrian `APIView` is meant to be the bare minimum without any extra utilities built into it, `GenericAPIView` on the other hand has functions for filtering, pagination, etc. built into it. If you look at how [ListModelMixin](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/4f7e9ed3bbb0fb3567884ef4e3d340bc2f77bc68/rest_framework/mixins.py#L39) (one of the classes `ListAPIview` inherits from) is implemented, our solution here looks very similar to it with the exception that ours is a bit specific.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks alot for the clarifications. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom filtering and ordering using `filter` and `order_by` respectively.

```py
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        query = Discussion.objects.all().order_by('id')
        title = request.query_params.get('title')
        if title is not None:
            query = query.filter(title=title)
        serializer = DiscussionSerializer(query, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Refrence: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters